# volumetric discrete Laplacian

Tags: discrete-geometry

The graph Laplacian is a common way to get a discretized version of the Laplacian differential operator on graphs and I recently learned about another discrete Laplacian for triangle meshes, often called cotangent Laplacian. Is there also an equivalent for volumetric models? (I guess, tetrahedral meshes). I found a few papers that mention something about it, but I'm not sure if this is as widely accepted / used as, say, the graph Laplacian, which seems to be pretty standard.